# ¿como ordenar una respuesta json si esta desordenada?

Tags: php, json, slim

Tengo un código en php que consulta datos desde la base de datos y devuelve una respuesta json lo que yo hago es recibir el json y luego retornarlo en el frontend el retorno del json funciona cuando hay un solo registro pero si hay mas de uno me esta armando el json con defectos por lo que hay error al retornar los valores al fronted como puedo armar un json sin error antes de retornarlo al fronted este es mi código php

```
$app->get(
  '/v20/operacion/dns/{codigo}',
  function ($request, $response, $args) {

    require __DIR__ . '/../src/connect.php';
    require __DIR__ . '/archivo.php';

    $codigo = $args['codigo'];

    //error_log("codes " .$codigo);
    try {
      $resultados_api = get_dns($codigo);
      $response = json_decode($resultados_api, true);

//error_log("Contenido de \$response: de extensiones " . json_encode($response));
// Verificar si el código en la respuesta es "200"

      if (!empty($response)) {

// Construir la respuesta JSON con los datos de la bd

//error_log("imprimiendo desde la bd geter");
//error_log("Contenido de \$response1: get " . json_encode($response));

        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        $json = json_encode(
          array(
            'cod' => 200,
            'status' => 'ok',
            'message' => 'Success',
            'data' => $response
          ),
          JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
          | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK
          | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION
        );

        echo $json; // Imprimir la respuesta JSON con los datos de la API
      } else {

// Construir una respuesta con código 204 si no hay datos en la tabla

        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        $json = json_encode(
          array(
            'cod' => 204,
            'status' => 'no_content',
            'message' => 'No data available'
          ),
          JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
          | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK
          | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION
        );
        echo $json; // Imprimir la respuesta JSON con código 204
      }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

// Manejo de errores en la base de datos
      header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
      $json = json_encode(
        array(
          'cod' => 500,
          'status' => 'error',
          'message' => 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage()
        ),
        JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
        | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK
        | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION
      );
    echo $json;
  } 
});
```

**Del lado del fronted lo retorno  pero da null lo he revisado en los logs de mi servidor trae los datos correctamente pero con un json mal formado por lo que al retornar al fronted da null este es mi codigo el el fronted**

```
if(isset($_GET['codigo'])){

  $usu10 = $_GET['codigo'];

  error_log('user us'.$usu10);

//$solicitudJSON = get_curl('operacion/obtenerUsuario/'.$codigo);
//header('Location: dashboard_v1.php?codigo='.$usu10);
//$solicitudJSON    = get_curl('operacion/dnsa/' .$usu10);

  $solicitudJSON = get_curl('operacion/dnsa/' . $usu10);

  error_log("Respuesta de la API dns: " . $solicitudJSON);

  $responseData = json_decode($solicitudJSON, true);

  error_log(
    "Datos recibidos DE LA API: " . json_encode($responseData)
  );
}
```

**El json que retorna es el siguiente**

```json
{"cod":200,"status":"ok","message":"Success","data":

{"code":"315771","name":"ns1","ip":"127.1.0.0"}}

{"cod":200,"status":"ok","message":"Success","data":

{"code":"315772","name":"ns2","ip":"127.1.0.0"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veamos si te ayudo en algo.

Te lo pondré en este Snippet comentado

```php
// Lo más probale es que la API te retorne un JSON como este
$codigo = '{"code":"315771","name":"ns1","ip":"127.1.0.0"}';

// Tu lo decodificas, lo conviertes en un array
$response = json_decode($codigo, true);

// Armas tu array
$array = array(
    'cod' => 200,
    'status' => 'ok',
    'message' => 'Success',
    // Acá lo que le pasas en un array (que debe estar bien formateado)
    'data' => $response
);

// Aca puedes comprobar el resultado (* esto es debuggear el código)
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

/*
    Array
    (
        [cod] => 200
        [status] => ok
        [message] => Success
        [data] => Array
            (
                [code] => 315771
                [name] => ns1
                [ip] => 127.1.0.0
            )

    )
*/

// Tu array lo conviertes en JSON
$json = json_encode(
      $array,
      JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
      | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK
      | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION
    );

// Resultado
echo $json;

// {"cod":200,"status":"ok","message":"Success","data":{"code":315771,"name":"ns1","ip":"127.1.0.0"}}
```

Si pasas el JSON del resultado a [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.org/f46e22) verás que todo esta correcto.

Porque cuando pones el JSON resultante pones dos respuestas?? Porque en jsonformatter si cojo cada resultado por aparte dice que el formato es correcto.

Necesitas dos resultados diferentes o los dos resultados en un mismo JSON??

Comment: mi sospecha es que hay una peticion doble o nos falta ver un foreach para "pero si hay mas de uno" pq si en get_dns viene un array con dos items luego del jsnoadodesenjsonado debería mantenerse

Comment: También convierte (a la brava) un JSON del API poniéndole corchetes en la línea de `$codigo = $args['codigo']`. Si yo hago eso en mi ambiente me da error. Se que algo no vemos porque sus JSON resultantes (uno por uno) se supone tienen buen formato pero lo que el dice que es el resultado (2 JSON) es lo que ya no funciona bien. Por eso recreé todo para ver si ayuda un poco al OP a ubicarse. Espero nos informe más de esto.